How to create TCP Tunelling?
I want to connect to a remote machine using SSH. Unfortunately, it seems that the SSH ports are closed. I found the following solution, but it is not convincing and relies on commercial software (Anydesk).
The remote machine does not have a monitor or dummy HDMI. I can connect to this remote machine via Anydesk, but I can only see a black screen. I then create a TCP tunnel as shown in the figure below.

While Anydesk is running, I can connect to the remote machine via SSH using the following command line:
ssh -p 2223 user@127.0.0.1

I want to achieve this without depending on any commercial software. Do you have any ideas on how I can connect via SSH?

Something VERY wrong or VERY missing from your description. The screenshot shown does not provide any connectivity outside localhost.

There are two important questions that will determine which kind of solutions are applicable to your situation.
1.) Is the IP address of your local machine and/or the remote machine within any of the following ranges:

10.0.0.0 .. 10.255.255.255
100.64.0.0 .. 100.127.255.255
172.16.0.0 .. 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0 .. 192.168.255.255

If it is, then that machine is not directly accessible from the internet, but is behind a Network Address Translation layer (NAT for short).
2.) The second question is, if there is a NAT, do you have access to change its configuration?


If neither machine is behind a NAT, then the only limit is firewalls. If there is even a single free port that allows incoming connections to the remote machine, you will be able to use it with SSH in a pretty straightforward way: either change the /etc/ssh/sshd_config of the remote machine so that sshd will listen on a non-default port, or start a second sshd process with a custom port. However, given that IPv4 addresses are running out worldwide, this situation is becoming more and more unlikely.

If the remote machine is behind a NAT, but your local machine isn't (or you can control the NAT on your side to enable a port forwarding for an incoming connection), you could configure the remote machine to always keep a SSH connection active to your local machine, and run a reverse TCP tunnel on it, similar to what you did with AnyDesk but in the opposite direction. Essentially, the remote computer would run:


    ssh -R 2223:localhost:22 someaccount@your.local.machine

Then, this would allow you to run ssh -p 2223 user@127.0.0.1 on your local machine to connect to the remote machine, just as before.
There are tools like autossh or keepssh for automating such a connection.

Alternatively, if the remote machine/both machines behind a NAT but making the remote accessible from public internet is acceptable, and the remote NAT can be configured to forward ports: configure the remote router to pass incoming connections to a specific port (e.g. TCP 2223) from any address on the internet to port 22 on the remote machine's private IP address. If you do this, you must ensure that all accounts on the remote machine that allow a SSH login are configured either to allow SSH authentication only, or to have very strong passwords at the very least.

Then you would probably need to set up some way to find out the current public IP address of the remote machine, perhaps a dynamic DNS client on the remote machine.
After configuring all that, you could then connect to the remote machine with:
ssh -p 2223 user@<DNS or IP of remote router>


If the NAT is not under your control at either end (i.e. port forwardings not available), then you'll need some publicly-accessible intermediate server (e.g. a small cloud VM) that can act as the endpoint of a reverse SSH tunnel like in option 2). When you are using AnyDesk, their cloud infrastructure fulfills this role and allows their software to set up the tunnel so the user won't have to care about the NAT details in between.

